# AWS SDK doesn't work on Azure Web App service

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a web app in .net core and deployed it on Azure (App Service).  As a part of the app, I am creating AWS RDS MySql db. The code works well on my machine but not on the Azure. Following code snippet which is exposed as a REST API is causing a problem.

```
logger.LogInfo("In AWSRDS.cs->PushToCloud()");
AmazonRDSClient client = new AmazonRDSClient(awsAccessKeyId:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        awsSecretAccessKey:"xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
logger.LogInfo("In AWSRDS.cs-> client created");
```

The above lines are wrapped with try-catch block. I get first line in the log file and nothing thereafter. No processing, no exception.

I alrady tried

1. re-deployments
2. restarting the app a few times
3. manually installing dotnet package via console on the Azure web app (even if the DLL exists)
4. Created another Azure web app (with linux hosting) only to observe same behaviour

Any clue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: No. I changed to approach to use REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you aren't getting any error message but I suspect the SDK is failing to resolve what AWS region to make requests to. When running in AWS the compute environment will be configured for the region the code is running and I suspect locally you have a default region configured.

Can you switch to the constructor that takes in a region enum and pass in the region you want to connect to?

Comment: Thanks Norm. Tried that already and it didn’t work. In fact I always use region. Since it’s not working I thought to give it a try without the region. Either way, it’s not working :-(